# Bookshelf query and update value in a single step

Tags: node.js, orm, bookshelf.js

I am using Bookshelf JS as my ORM. I want to query for a special entity and update it one query (as if I execute INSERT INTO... WHERE...)

How can I do this without a raw query?

Here is how I do it right now:

```
async function updateSetting() { 
  let userSetting = await Setting.where({user: 1, key: 'foo'}).fetch()
  await userSetting.save({value: {confirmed: true, order: 66}})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update a model without doing a `fetch()` you need to have the model's `id_Attribute` (usually just `id`) or to use a `where()` clause (as mentioned by @websoftwares)

Something just like:

```
new Setting({ id: 99 })
  .save({ value: { confirmed: true, order: 66} },
        { patch: true })
```

Note in this case you do not need to specify the `method` because the presence of `id` implies you are updating an existing row.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
async function updateSetting() {
    let userSetting = await Setting
        .where({user: 1, key: 'foo'})
        .save(
            {value: {confirmed: true, order: 66}},
            {method: 'update', patch: true}
        )
}
```